# Bluetooth Dongle doesn't show up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bluetooth, dongle

I recently bought a Siyoteam Model HK-968 Bluetooth dongle. My desktop pc is running Windows 7 Proffesinal 64bit. The windows couldn't find the driver or even indentfy the device, it showed up as a **"Unknown Device"** in **"Other Devices"** category in Device Manager. I googled for 2 hours to find the drivers because I couldn't find Siyoteam official page for drivers. None of them worked. Then I decided to use an Driver update app called "Driver Easy". It found and installed the **CSR Bluetooth Device** driver. Now my dongle was put in **Bluetooth USB** category.

[image: Bluetooth created]

But still no bluetooth icon showed to scan and connect with devices. I changed all Bluetooth Services to Automatic.
[image: bluetooth services]

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the device as well, it installed again but it still didnt show up.
I tried to disable the device and I disabled but then when I pressed enable it caused a BSOD. I tried again but it caused a BSOD again. Then I tried to disable and enable it in Safe Mode and it disabled and enabled it. Still nothing. And when the drivers weren't installed the light in the dongle would light but now that the drivers are installed it doesnt. What should I do?

### More Driver info:

- Its file is btcusb.sys
- Hardware Ids: USB\VID_0A12&PID_0001&REV_1958 **and** USB\VID_0A12&PID_0001
- Capabilities: 00000080 **and** CM_DEVCAP_SURPRISEREMOVALOK
- Driver provider: IVT Corporation
- Driver date: 24/06/2010
- Driver Version: 6.2.71.214
- Driver key: {9b21fd3a-b1ab-4eb9-956f-e56acfe78bce}\0003
- Service: Btcsrusb

(I don't know if this info is useful or not)

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the adapter

Get rid of the 'Driver Easy' program.

Control Panel (Large Icons)\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features

Find 'Driver Easy' > UNINSTALL  Reboot if instructed

Go to:

https://www.drvhub.net/devices/bluetooth-devices/cambridge-silicon-radio/csr-bluetooth

and download the driver, and unarchive it to a known location.

Plug in the adapter.

Go to Device Manager and find the adapter.  Right click, go to Properties > Driver > Update Driver > Browse My computer for Drivers > and go to the folder of your known location.  Point to the rtkfilter.inf file and follow the prompts.

As a rule, NEVER use a free driver manager, or pretty much anything marked 'free' online.

Comment: I still get "Windows encountered a problem installing the driver software for your device
Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error while atepmting to install it.
 **CSR Bluetooth Chip**
The system cannot find the file specified
 " error.
The path was correct (I put it in my desktop), I choosed the folder but still got this error. (Note: This is the second device Im trying)

Comment: Try this link, it matches your hardware id:  https://www.drvhub.net/devices/network/cambridge-silicon-radio/bcm2045-bluetooth-v2-0-dongle

Comment: I sometimes wonder why simple devices like this get so many changes, hence, so many different drivers..Something to do with money undoubtedly.....  If that one doesn't work go back to the first page and try all the drivers that work with Windows 7 x64.  One of them has to work.   Good luck!  Also, make sure the folder you put the drivers in has permissions set to Everyone > Full access just in case that is the issue.(Unlikely but possible)

Comment: The driver you linked indentified the dongle as a USB **Model : CSR8510 A10** and all I can do is eject it. I will try other drivers in the page you linked

Answer (score 0):

thanks, man. I had the same problem  with same Bluetooth Driver Version: 6.2.71.214  and did not find the right driver so I went the link that you suggested and get the

Cambridge Silicon Radio CSR Bluetooth
Driver type: Bluetooth devices
Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Corp
Version: 1.3.1016.1 (01 Jul 2019)
*.inf file: rtkfilter.inf

and follow the step as you suggested and it worked fine for me. To the people out there in the world, even if you have a different version of Bluetooth, try to change the driver version. it will help you a lot. Thanks.